# Where is getScreenshotAs method defined?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, takesscreenshot

I was going through Screenshot code in selenium. Below is the code for it :

```
File src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.File);
```

In the above line, TakesScreenshot is an interface and getScreenshotAs is a method. So what I understand from this is, we are typecasting driver into TakesScreenshot interface which essentially means that our driver will behave like TakesScreenshot from now after which getScreenshotAs method will be executed.

My question here is that an interface can only have abstract methods. So, how is getScreenshotAs method is executed through TakesScreenshot interface as it would not have any definition of this method. More precisely, where is getScreenshotAs method defined and how does the above line of code works ?

---

Adding a few more details :

TakesScreenshot --> an interface

driver --> instance of ChromeDriver class (WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())

getScreenshotAs --> method in TakesScreenshot interface.

The above code is used to take screenshot of webpages in selenium.

Comment: what is `TakesScreenshot ` and `driver`, you need to post at least part of the code

Comment: What you actually want to know not clear

Comment: dude if you know selenium, you would know this is the entire code for taking screenshot.

Comment: But, dude you aren't asking selenium question . are you ? You are asking question related to java

Comment: I know, But your question is regarding execution

Comment: File is a class which is used to Implement method of takesScreenshot  Interface

Comment: Now, you are coming to the point. So, I'm repeating my question again *what is `TakesScreenshot` and `driver`*. The person, who knows OOPs doesn't mean he/she knew selenium also. am I right ? But, other way it is possible

Comment: @iamsankalp89 I don't think File class implements TakesScreenshot interface methods.

Comment: getScreenshotAs method which will capture the entire screenshot in form of file.  simple. File is a class

Comment: I really don't understand, why he is hiding his code. It's impossible to tell what he is asking without seeing the code. This is my last comment. All the best to OP for getting the answer

Comment: It is not be a clear question

Comment: not hiding any code..not sure why the question is not clear..if you want some more info let me know I ll add it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The method `getScreenshotAs` is implemented in [RemoteWebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java) class. You can't use it from your `driver` instance because you used the `WebDriver` interface, which doesn't extends `TakesScreenshot` interface, to create the `driver` instance.

Casting to (or using in the first place) `RemoteWebDriver` or `ChromeDriver` will also allow you to use the method.

```
File src = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.File);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me break down you code for an explaination:

```
File src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.File);
```

into these 2 lines:

```
TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

---

### Analysis

As per the documentation, *TakesScreenshot* is an interface in *Selenium* within the `org.openqa.selenium` package. `public interface TakesScreenshot` indicates that a driver that can capture a screenshot and store it in the below mentioned different ways. `public interface TakesScreenshot` has a known *Subinterface* as *WebElement*. The known Implementing Classes are :

1. **ChromeDriver**
2. **FirefoxDriver**
3. **InternetExplorerDriver**
4. **EdgeDriver**
5. **OperaDriver**
6. **RemoteWebDriver**
7. **RemoteWebElement`**
8. **SafariDriver**
9. **EventFiringWebDriver**

In the first line we are initializing an instance of *TakesScreenshot* as `ts` and casting the *WebDriver* instance i.e `driver` to that instance.

In the second line we are trying to capture the screenshot and storing it in a specified location. For *WebDriver* extending `TakesScreenshot`, this makes a best effort depending on the browser (casted) to return the following object in order of preference :

1. *Entire page*
2. *Current window*
3. *Visible portion of the current frame*
4. *The screenshot of the entire display containing the browser*

`getScreenshotAs()` method returns the Object in which is stored information about the screenshot is contained. On failure `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` which means the underlying implementation does not support screenshot capturing mechanism.

You can find the details documentation [here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html).

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to take screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-to-take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver/55120087#55120087)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I understand, it's not actually a selenium-specific question, but basic Java question.

The meaning of the expression you provided:

```
((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.File)
```

is following: no matter what is the type of `driver` variable, in this line we are sure that it implements `TakesScreenshot` interface which has `getScreenshotAs` method. So we're casting type to `TakesScreenshot` and call `getScreenshotAs` method on the `driver` object. The implementation of this method is inside real `driver` class whichever it is.

To give you an example which will be really close to the question code (I made this method to accept `Object` so we really need to cast `o` to the target interface. Don't do it in real code):

```
public void log(Object o) {
  ((Printable) o).print();
}
```

where `Printable` is some interface with method `print`:

```
public interface Printable {
  void print();
}
```

so if we have some implementation of `Printable` like

```
public class Greeting implements Printable {

  @Override
  public void print() {
    System.out.println("Hello, username");
  }

}
```

we can call

```
log(new Greeting())
```

which result in line "Hello, username"

Edit:

As I can see in JavaDoc to selenium, `WebDriver` interface does not extend  `TakesScreenshot` interface. So if the type of `driver` variable is `WebDriver` interface you have to cast it. `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()` - there is only reference of type `WebDriver` for compiler. Despite the fact that real class is `ChromeDriver` compiler doesn't know it. So in this case in order to call `getScreenshotAs` method you have to cast `driver` to `TakesScreenshot` (and it's safe as `driver` is instance of `ChromeDriver` which implements both `WebDriver` and `TakesScreenshot` interfaces). Only after that you can call `getScreenshotAs` method from `TakesScreenshot` interface.

Well, as I understand, it's not actually a selenium-specific question, but basic Java question.

The meaning of the expression you provided:

```
((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.File)
```

is following: no matter what is the type of `driver` variable, in this line we are sure that it implements `TakesScreenshot` interface which has `getScreenshotAs` method. So we're casting type to `TakesScreenshot` and call `getScreenshotAs` method on the `driver` object. The implementation of this method is inside real `driver` class whichever it is.

To give you an example which will be really close to the question code (I made this method to accept `Object` so we really need to cast `o` to the target interface. Don't do it in real code):

```
public void log(Object o) {
  ((Printable) o).print();
}
```

where `Printable` is some interface with method `print`:

```
public interface Printable {
  void print();
}
```

so if we have some implementation of `Printable` like

```
public class Greeting implements Printable {

  @Override
  public void print() {
    System.out.println("Hello, username");
  }

}
```

we can call

```
log(new Greeting())
```

which result in line "Hello, username"

Edit:

As I can see in JavaDoc to selenium, `WebDriver` interface does not extend  `TakesScreenshot` interface. So if the type of `driver` variable is `WebDriver` interface you have to cast it. `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()` - there is only reference of type `WebDriver` for compiler. Despite the fact that real class is `ChromeDriver` compiler doesn't know it. So in this case in order to call `getScreenshotAs` method you have to cast `driver` to `TakesScreenshot` (and it's safe as `driver` is instance of `ChromeDriver` which implements both `WebDriver` and `TakesScreenshot` interfaces). Only after that you can call `getScreenshotAs` method from `TakesScreenshot` interface.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
// driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.File); // compilation error as there is no method getScreenshotAs in WebDriver interface
((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.File); // ok after explicit casting
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation...but if the implementation of getScreenshotAs method is inside my main driver class, then what is the need to typecasting ?

Comment: casting is needed if the type of `driver ` differ from `TakesScreenshot ` interface and it's implementations (as `Object o` in my example). If in your code `driver` variable is either `TakesScreenshot driver` or any implementation class of `TakesScreenshot` (e.g. `ChromeDriver  driver`) you do not need casting and can call method `getScreenshotAs ` directly on `driver` variable.

Comment: So, essentially you are saying that if my driver is an instance of ChromeDriver then I can directly write driver.getScreenshotAs, is that correct ?

Comment: got it..if that is the case not sure why people typecast driver to TakesScreenshot first before taking screenshots in selenium..any guesses on it ?

Comment: I've added an Edit block to my answer (after clarifications in your question I haven't seen before)

Comment: so that means we are going from :WebDriver driver = new ChromDriver() to TakesScreenshot driver = new ChromeDriver()..is it correct ?